# Basic Test is failing on Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, testing

I'm trying to code my first test.

I tried to run the out-the-box test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

with

```
php artisan test
```

But I get:

```
➜  acc git:(master) ✗ php artisan test

   PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
  ✓ basic test

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ✕ basic test

  Tests:  1 failed, 1 passed

  Expected status code 200 but received 500. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.

  at tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:18
    14|     public function testBasicTest()
    15|     {
    16|         $response = $this->get('/');
    17| 
  > 18|         $response->assertStatus(200);
    19|     }
    20| }
    21|
```

When I go to chrome to : `http://localhost:8000` I get a 200.

Why is it happening ?

Comment: Could you add `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` at the start of your test, it should then tell you why you are receiving a 500 status.

Comment: ```dd($response->exception)``` and share it please.

Comment: there are many reasons why this could happen, how does the route look like etc. etc?

Comment: with $this->withoutExceptionHandling();, I could see what was the error. auth()->user() is not working with phpunit. You can put it as answer, this is how I could debug it

Comment: @Juliatzin It's giving you 500 (Internal Server error) because there is something wrong in the controller function. Please share the controller function that is being called at this route.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test controller actions which are using `auth()->user()`, you'd need to modify your tests to set the user, like:

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $user = new User([
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'email' => 'test@user'
    ]);
    
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```